# Convert string answer to number.

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector that is the answer to the question "Please indicate your age".

The problem is that the answer is a string. So, so good people answers take many different and crazy forms.

Some answers are "32"; "32 years"; "32 años"; "About to complete 70 years"; "old, very old......... mid-forties"; "by 7th october 2013, i'm 31yo"; "Eighteen Years of Age"; etc etc

Is there a way to convert as much of these data as possible to numbers and the rest to NAs? (Doing it by hand is not desirable an option because there are thousand of observations)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this that will yeild any reliability. That is, think of a number as just another charachter in a sea of an Almanac's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
L <- lapply(regmatches(s, gregexpr("[0-9\\.]+",s)), as.numeric)
```

Result (`s <- "by 7th october 2013, i'm 31yo"`):

```
# [[1]]
# [1]    7 2013   31
```

To get back a numeric vector with `NA` where the list `L` above has more than one number, use this:

```
result <- rep(NA, length(L))
ok <- sapply(L, length)==1
result[ok] <- unlist(L[ok])
```

BTW: You may also wanto to remove the "\." in the regex above to avoid non integer results.

Comment: (+1) Using the OP examples: `example <- c("32", "32 years", "32 años", "About to complete 70 years", "old","very old","mid-forties", "by 7th october 2013, i'm 31yo", "Eighteen Years of Age");as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]","",example))` gives a weird result. The OP could always filter out values larger than 100.

Comment: @dayne, you're right, I've changed the answer to be more general.

Comment: how can i get a numeric vector instead of a list. I have tried unlist, but i get an error "replacement has 4100 rows, data has 4101"

Comment: @Ignacio You can use the original answer, still available in my comment, but you will run into issues with things like "by 7th october 2013, i'm 31yo". I can appreciate not wanting to do it manually, but if you only have a few thousand entries and the rest of the data is good, it might be worth taking two days and going through it.

Comment: @Ignacio, given a character vector `s`, the code above will return a list of numeric vectors, each list element corresponding to an elemente of `s`. The problem here is that some strings may have more than one number (like the one above), while others may have less or even none. How do you want to deal with such cases?

Comment: For now if the list does not have exactly one number, then I would like to get NA. Later I may try to fix it manually. Thanks a lot for the help!